# Convergence of series for $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)^k$ and $\left(\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^k}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I had these two problems I had to do to complete an assignment:

- $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)^k$
- $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^k}\right)$

after finishing these, I asked my professor to pre-check before turning it. He then said they were both wrong at certain parts. Can you tell me why??

Steps taken for: $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)^k$

$\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)^k=\frac{1}{\left(2k+1\right)^k}$  $=\left|\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2\left(k+1\right)+1}\right)^{k+1}}{\frac{1}{\left(2k+1\right)^k}}\right|$

$\left(\frac{1}{2\left(k+1\right)+1}\right)^{k+1}=\frac{1^{k+1}}{\left(2k+3\right)^{k+1}}$$=\left|\frac{\frac{1^{k+1}}{\left(2k+3\right)^{k+1}}}{\frac{1}{\left(2k+1\right)^k}}\right|$

$\frac{\frac{1^{k+1}}{\left(2k+3\right)^{k+1}}}{\frac{1}{\left(2k+1\right)^k}}$$=\left|\frac{1^{k+1}\left(2k+1\right)^k}{\left(2k+3\right)^{k+1}}\right|$

$=\left|\frac{\left(2k+1\right)^k}{\left(2k+3\right)^{k+1}}\right|$

= $\lim _{k\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{\left(2k+1\right)^k}{\left(2k+3\right)^{k+1}}\right|\right)=0$

$\lim _{k\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(\infty +1\right)^{\infty }}{\left(\infty +3\right)^{\infty }}\right)=0$ *"<---this is where he said I went wrong"*

Converges

---

Steps Taken for: $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^k}\right)$

$\left|\frac{\frac{\left(2\left(k+1\right)\right)!}{4^{\left(k+1\right)}}}{\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^k}}\right|$$=\left|\frac{\left(2\left(k+1\right)\right)!\cdot \:4^k}{4^{k+1}\left(2k\right)!}\right|$

$\frac{4^k\left(2\left(k+1\right)\right)!}{4^{k+1}\left(2k\right)!}$$=\frac{\left(2\left(k+1\right)\right)!}{4\left(2k\right)!}$

$=\frac{2\left(k+1\right)\left(2k+1\right)}{4}$ *"<-- this is where he said I went wrong"*

.
.
.
cont.

Comment: Use the root test for the first.

Comment: For the first one you are not wrong but there is a step missing to say in detail why that limit is actually zero, the second looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

by ratio test for positive series, we get

$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{(2k+1)^k}{(2k+3)^{k+1}}\leq\frac{(2k+3)^k}{(2k+3)^{k+1}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2k+3}$$

the limit is $0<1$, thus the series converges.

> for the second

by ratio test, we get

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2(k+1)(2k+1)}{4},$$ the limit is $+\infty$ and the series diveges.

Comment: ok 0 < 1 makes diference

Comment: @TemurBakhriddinov the most important part is that you have to show why your term with infinities in it actually goes to zero... The reason for that is the inequalities in this answer. This proves that the limit is less than one (zero in fact) which shows convergence